# Why I can't use month_ret.rolling(36).std()*np.sqrt(12) ? (Python finance)

Tags: python, std, finance, yfinance

I would like to know why the following code doesn't work ? Indeed I would like to have a rolling annualized risk mesure of the SP500. First I've imported data from yahoo finance. I've selected the close price and taken the last close price of eache month. Then I wanted the return of each date with the 36 close month period back. Same with risk metrics.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

SP500=yf.download("SPY", start = "2020-01-01", end = "2020-12-01")
close = SP500.loc[:, "Close"].copy()
month_ret = close.resample("M", kind = "period").last().pct_change().dropna()
month_ret["Return"] = month_ret.rolling(36).mean()*12
month_ret["Risk"] = month_ret.rolling(36).std()*np.sqrt(12)
month_ret.tail()

I've got the following message:


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in _prep_values(self, values)
    231             try:
--> 232                 values = ensure_float64(values)
    233             except (ValueError, TypeError):

pandas\_libs\algos_common_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.algos.ensure_float64()

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in _apply(self, func, name, window, center, check_minp, **kwargs)
    911             try:
--> 912                 values = self._prep_values(b.values)
    913 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in _prep_values(self, values)
    234                 raise TypeError(
--> 235                     "cannot handle this type -> {0}" "".format(values.dtype)
    236                 )

TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-6480c4316ca2> in <module>
----> 1 month_ret["Risk"] = month_ret.rolling(36).std()*np.sqrt(12)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in std(self, ddof, *args, **kwargs)
   1886     def std(self, ddof=1, *args, **kwargs):
   1887         nv.validate_rolling_func("std", args, kwargs)
-> 1888         return super().std(ddof=ddof, **kwargs)
   1889 
   1890     @Substitution(name="rolling")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in std(self, ddof, *args, **kwargs)
   1292 
   1293         return self._apply(
-> 1294             f, "std", check_minp=_require_min_periods(1), ddof=ddof, **kwargs
   1295         )
   1296 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in _apply(self, func, name, window, center, check_minp, **kwargs)
    918                     continue
    919                 else:
--> 920                     raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
    921 
    922             if values.size == 0:

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two causes of the error The second is that the calculation of the risk value is not specified in the return column, which leads to the error that the NaN value is included in the calculation. Since I am not familiar with investments, does the following code meet the intent of your question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

SP500=yf.download("SPY", start = "2015-01-01", end = "2020-12-01")
close = SP500.loc[:, ["Close"]].copy()
month_ret = close.resample("M", kind="period").last().pct_change().dropna()
month_ret["Return"] = month_ret.rolling(36).mean()*12
month_ret.fillna(0, inplace=True)
month_ret["Risk"] = month_ret['Return'].rolling(36).std()*np.sqrt(12)

month_ret.tail(37)
Close   Return  Risk
Date            
2017-11     0.030566    0.000000    NaN
2017-12     0.006981    0.092355    0.053321
2018-01     0.056359    0.121018    0.086672
2018-02     -0.036360   0.090163    0.099274
2018-03     -0.031290   0.086426    0.108837
2018-04     0.005168    0.084871    0.116688
2018-05     0.024309    0.088689    0.124241
2018-06     0.001255    0.097458    0.132499
2018-07     0.037047    0.102278    0.140553
2018-08     0.031920    0.133234    0.154062
2018-09     0.001412    0.143890    0.167868
2018-10     -0.069104   0.092502    0.170876
2018-11     0.018549    0.097467    0.173960
2018-12     -0.093343   0.074052    0.174226
2019-01     0.080066    0.117336    0.178965
2019-02     0.032416    0.128416    0.184521
2019-03     0.013636    0.112365    0.186919
2019-04     0.040852    0.124669    0.190188
2019-05     -0.063771   0.097741    0.189812
2019-06     0.064410    0.119783    0.191078
2019-07     0.015119    0.112665    0.190892
2019-08     -0.016743   0.106685    0.189555
2019-09     0.014772    0.113265    0.188173
2019-10     0.022105    0.126412    0.187371
2019-11     0.036198    0.126199    0.185726
2019-12     0.024021    0.129441    0.183558
2020-01     -0.000404   0.123342    0.179933
2020-02     -0.079166   0.083856    0.173722
2020-03     -0.129987   0.041556    0.168637
2020-04     0.126984    0.080575    0.161391
2020-05     0.047645    0.091753    0.153379
2020-06     0.013275    0.095681    0.144406
2020-07     0.058892    0.108460    0.134495
2020-08     0.069797    0.130753    0.124329
2020-09     -0.041281   0.111955    0.110565
2020-10     -0.024934   0.095790    0.093477
2020-11     0.108777    0.121860    0.071686
```